# Question regarding Cauchy Sequence in a proof

Tags: real-analysis

Here is a theorem regarding convergence of Gradient Descent from Ovidiu Calin's Deep Learning Architecture. However, I think the converse direction is wrong.

[image]

[image]

The convergence for Cauchy, as far as I recall, should be uniform in $p$. For example, take one dimensional
\begin{align*}
x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
\end{align*}
Then clearly for every fixed $p$, $\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+p}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, while $x_n$ is not convergent.

Comment: You are right. The proof is wrong.